# Storing game state when game state includes functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, local-storage

I'm working on a simple web game and need to enable saving game state so users can pick up where they left off after closing their browser or refreshing the page. The game runs entirely in the browser and uses basic HTML/CSS/Javascript.

I'm currently using local-storage, because it provides a simple solution to the problem of saving game state across sessions:

```
function saveGame() {
  window.localStorage.setItem('gameData', JSON.stringify(game));
}

function loadGame() {
  game = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('gameData'));
}
```

However, my game state includes an array of functions, and an array of objects containing functions. When I load up the previous game state, these functions and objects are not loaded properly because functions cannot be transformed into JSON (at least - not easily. I've tried toString()ing my functions and the eval()ing them, and though they seemed to store properly, I could not retrieve them. Either way this feels like a poor solution).

Is there a better way to save and recover game state that includes functions? Is this a data model issue? Additionally, I have cases where HTML is modified programatically. Can HTML be stored as well and later reloaded so the modified HTML sticks around after a reload?

Edit: Adding the game object for your reference:

```
function Game() {
  this.player = new Player();
  this.triggerFnSet = new Set();
  this.tasks = [];
  this.activeTask = undefined;
  this.resources = { fame: {},
                     money: {},
                     beats: { instrument: "laptop",
                              clicksPer: 30,
                              xpPer: 5 },
                     samples: { instrument: "laptop",
                               resourcesPer: 25,
                               requiredResource: "beats",
                               xpPer: 50 },
                     notes: { instrument: "keyboard",
                              clicksPer: 50,
                              xpPer: 5 },
                     measures: { instrument: "keyboard",
                                 resourcesPer: 25,
                                 requiredResource: "notes",
                                 xpPer: 50 }
                    };
  this.specialResources = { songs: { instruments: ["laptop", "keyboard"],
                                     resourcesPer: 50,
                                     validResources: ["samples", "measures"],
                                     xpPer: 500 }};
  this.instruments = { laptop: { level: 1,
                                 currentTempo: "slow",
                                 tempoSpeeds: { slowest: 25,
                                                slow: 15,
                                                fast: 10,
                                                fastest: 5 },
                                 dropActive: false },
                       keyboard: { currentNote: undefined,
                                   currentSong: undefined }
                     };
};
```

The problematic fields are tasks and triggerFnSet, where a task looks like:

```
function Task(name, tooltip, checkFn, failFn, startFn, tickFn, finishFn, timeToComplete) {
    this.name = name;
    this.tooltip = tooltip;
    this.checkFn = checkFn;
    this.failFn = failFn;
    this.startFn = startFn;
    this.tickFn = tickFn;
    this.finishFn = finishFn;
    this.timeToComplete = timeToComplete;
}
```

And a triggerFn looks like below, and is executed every in-game tick and removed from the list after returning true:

```
function firstBeatTrigger() {
  if (game.player.stats.beats.lifetime >= 1) {
    document.getElementById('beats').style.display = "block";
    appendToOutputContainer("You've created your first beat. A building block to something greater.");
    game.triggerFnSet.add(tenthBeatTrigger);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your game state should not include functions. You should be able to generate whatever you need from the game state, otherwise, is it really the games state?

Comment: Yes, this is a data model issue. You need to find a way to represent the state without functions. There's nothing wrong per se with using functions (compared to, e.g., class instances with attributes and a method), but they are hard to serialise/deserialise as you found out.

Comment: Can you show us how `game` looks like? If you are using closures, then you can't store them as code anyway. Transform them into objects that can be interpreted.

Comment: @Bergi I've added the game object and associated objects above. These functions are properly defined in the code (ie. they are not anonymous) so perhaps the game model should be referencing the functions in some other way, as opposed to holding the functions themselves.

Comment: @DerekPollard curious if you have any ideas how the game state should hold information about which functions should be executed?

Comment: @Ormannishe - the same way any application knows how to deal with a stream of data. As someone who has a game written in web technologies, I ship down the information needed to display the game and its functionality. Give me an example of where you think you need a function and I'll show you a better way of doing it

Comment: @DerekPollard Here's an example. The user reloads the game and has 999 lifetime beats. There are multiple triggers defined for when the user has achieved x numbers of beats (where x = 1, 10, 100, 500, 1000).

On reload, the game should only check the 1000 beats triggers (because the user has already finished the others). How do we know on reload which triggerFn to add? What ties the user's 999 beats to the associated function?

Comment: @Ormannishe so you ship down the user beat count and the triggers special `X` , along with trigger identifiers. In my game, we have a way to do missions. The user sends the backend the mission it needs to do, then the back end ships down the state of that mission (% complete, mission cost, results of executing, etc)

Comment: @Ormannishe Thanks for the example. Given that all the functions are named, you could e.g. store the name of the function in the game state. To serialise, get the name of the function. To deserialise, look up the function by name in an object.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your input! I've implemented something in that respect and it looks like it will work. To do the function look up during the deserialization, I can use the window object since my triggerFns are in a global scope

Comment: @Ormannishe I would in general recommend to avoid lookups in `window` for security reasons (who can control the data, what if the name is `eval` or something), but it depends and might be ok in your case

Comment: @Bergi understood, security is not a concern in this case since the entire application runs in the browser (ie. there are no server side operations)

Comment: @Ormannishe Security should still be a concern - e.g. if the `eval`ed data is controlled by an URL parameter, a user of your application can be hacked if you pass them a manipulated link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, most commenters here are correct in that this is mainly a data model issue. I am not looking to refactor the model, so I am considering the following workaround the correct answer:

Serialize functions as string references:

```
function saveGame() {
  var triggers = [];

  game.triggerFnSet.forEach(function (trigger){
    triggers.push(trigger.name);
  });

  // Serialize regular game data
  window.localStorage.setItem('gameData', JSON.stringify(game));

  // Serialize triggerFns
  window.localStorage.setItem('triggers', JSON.stringify(triggers));
}
```

Then deserialize by doing a lookup on the functions through the window object, converting them back to functions:

```
function loadGame() {
  var triggers = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('triggers'));
  var gameData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('gameData'));

  if (gameData !== null) {
    game = gameData;
    game.triggerFnSet = new Set();

    triggers.forEach(function (trigger){
      game.triggerFnSet.add(window[trigger]);
    });
  }
}
```

This works because my functions are not anonymous and exist in a global context that can be accessed easily by the window!

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you may have to map your deserialized object to a complete model with all the functions. Perhaps JSON merge from your preferred library. Also, I see no problems storing HTML as values in your JSON object.
But, really, separate your functions from your model. All functions should be a separate class. Call it gameEngine or something.

Comment: Most of my code is functional, leveraging functional principles to drive game state. The functions I'm trying to restore are properly defined functions (ie. I'm not worried about not having access to them on a reload). The issue is, part of the game's state is determined by what functions are valid for execution (in the case of triggers, the user can experience an event if the triggerFn for that event has been added to the set).

Maybe I'm not following your suggestions but I don't think a gameEngine class solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

While, as has been commented on, your game state should not rely on functions, it may be worth noting that the array of functions can be solved by referencing a key, rather than a function, and making sure that you always have an object holding possible functions available
So:
    `a={},
    a.m=function () {}`

and then call your array like this `a[array[1]]()` rather than `array[1]()`

This approach will not work easily with objects (unless they only host functions) without a fair bit of rewriting code which could be better spent on a cleaner solution which splits logic from data.

Comment: I have implemented a version of this which seems to work. Instead of storing the functions in storage, I store function.name. For deserialization I then do a lookup on the required function using window[functionName] and add it to the game object.

Answer (score -1):

```
function t(l){
   return l+1;
}

eval("("+t.toString()+")")(1)
```

this seems to work **but I dont recommend it**

on top of that doing `eval("function t(l){ return l+1;}")` //without the brackets

registers the function into the window object allowing you to then call it

```
t(2);
```

(even though it wont return it)